# ASP.NET Templated Control

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls, itemplate

I'm attempting to build a templated control.  You'll see that as part of the Field section, I'd like to be able to define controls as children.  When I attempt to compile I'm receiving the error message "***MyTemplateControl.Field' does not have a public property named 'Button'***".  Does anyone know how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Below you'll find an example XHTML markup, and below that my control implementation.

> I've editted my example to hopefully clarify what I'm looking for.  Thanks everyone for the MSDN links.  I've been through those already.
>   What I'm trying to build is a data entry control that will auto format a table for me.  We do a lot of data entry webforms, and I'd like to ease the implementation time.

```
<cc1:MyForm ID="MyForm1" runat="server">
    <ViewTemplate>
        <cc1:Field Question="What is your name?">
            <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" />
        </cc1:Field>
    </ViewTemplate>
    <EditTemplate>
        <cc1:Field Question="What is your name?">
            <asp:Textbox ID="myTextbox" runat="server" />
        </cc1:Field>
    </EditTemplate>
</cc1:MyForm>
```

---

```
public class MyForm : WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    private FieldCollection _fieldCollection;
    private FieldCollection _field2Collection;

    public FieldCollection ViewTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_fieldCollection == null)
            {
                _fieldCollection = new FieldCollection();
            }
            return _fieldCollection;
        }
    }

    public FieldCollection EditTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            if (_field2Collection == null)
            {
                _field2Collection = new FieldCollection();
            }
            return _field2Collection;
        }
    }
}

public class FieldCollection : CollectionBase
{
   .
   .
   .
}

[ParseChildren(false)]
public class Field 
{ 
   . 
   . 
   . 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's something strange in your implementation. It's difficult to understand what you'd like to do, either to build a templated control, or a control on which you can add a list of child controls.

For the templated approach you'd have to do something like this:

```
public class MyForm : WebControl, INamingContainer
{

   private TemplateOwner templateOwner{ get; set; }

   private ITemplate _Content;
   public ITemplate Content
   {
      get
      {
         return this._Content;
      }
      set
      {
         _Content = value;
      }
   }

   protected override void CreateChildControls()
   {
      base.Controls.Clear();

      templateOwner = new TemplateOwner();
      this.Content.InstantiateIn(templateOwner);

      this.Controls.Add(templateOwner);
   }

   ...
}

[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class TemplateOwner : WebControl{

  public TemplateOwner():base(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
  {
  }
}
```

The usage would then look like

```
<cc1:MyForm ID="MyForm1" runat="server">
    <Content>
        <!-- Place whatever HTML, ASP.net controls etc you like -->
    </Content>
</cc1:MyForm>
```

You still have to add the appropriate annotations to configure the behavior of the designer. I just wrote this down quickly to give you an idea.

Comment: Close, but I need it to be further extended.  See my editted question.

Comment: ehm..well. Just add another property like "Content" which is of type ITemplate and continue. It should work. Your thing with the collection isn't needed. Within a template you can put whatever you want, so you can forget about the FieldCollection. Otherwise what you want to achieve is not a template and you have to go for the FieldCollection-way. These are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

GridView also doesn't allow such manipulation, 
Instead use MyForm1.FindControl("mybutton")

Also I have notice your template is not derived from ITemplate interface. As usual ASP.Net also uses System.Web.UI.Control as base class for this impl.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code:

```
public partial class SmallFramedControl : UserControl, INamingContainer 
{
    private TemplateOwner templateOwner { get; set; }
    private ITemplate _Content;
    public ITemplate Content
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Content;
        }
        set
        {
            _Content = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        //base.Controls.Clear();
        templateOwner = new TemplateOwner();
        this.Content.InstantiateIn(templateOwner);
        plchAdd.Controls.Add(templateOwner);
    }



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class TemplateOwner : WebControl
{
    public TemplateOwner()
        : base(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div)
    {
    }
}
```

and ascx page look like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
            CodeBehind="SmallFramedControl.ascx.cs"
            Inherits="OtPortalNewDesign.UserControls.SmallFramedControl" %>
```

this will be top of frame

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plchAdd" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

this will be bottom of frame